# Remove additional object properties from a GORM for MongoDB query output

Tags: json, groovy, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I'm using GORM for MongoDB in a standalone groovy application (no grails).
I need to render these objects as json, but GORM results contains additional properties that must be "hidden" in the returned json output.

How can I remove them for every mapped object and get only plain objects?

A solution without custom code for every entity will be best.

```
@Entity
class Invoice {
    String name
    List<InvoiceItem> items

    static embedded = ['items']
}
@Entity
class InvoiceItem {
    String description
    int qt
}
```

Printed properties of the object `def i = Invoice.getByName("MyFirstInvoice")`

```
[
collectionName:invoice, 
gormPersistentEntity:Invoice, 
async:org.grails.datastore.gorm.async.GormAsyncStaticApi@6991948, 
id:3, 
gormDynamicFinders: [
    org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindOrCreateByFinder@3337ff9, org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindOrSaveByFinder@6bb41fe3, org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindByFinder@517fcc04, org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder@1fe2dc3a, org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByBooleanFinder@736a488, org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindByBooleanFinder@4c36e88a, org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.CountByFinder@630612e4, org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.ListOrderByFinder@6a0c11b2], 
items:[InvoiceItem : (unsaved), InvoiceItem : (unsaved)],
name:MyFirstInvoice, 
DB:com.mongodb.MongoDatabaseImpl@58acea9f, 
attached:false, 
class:class Invoice, 
version:0, 
dirtyPropertyNames:[], 
errors:org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors, 
collection:com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl@23253bb8, 
transients:[], 
dirty:false, count:2, 
embedded:[items]
]
```

The expected output is something like:

```
[name:MyFirstInvoice, items:[[description:one, qt:1], [description:two, qt:2]]]
```

Comment: Similiar unwanted properties show up in grails too. However, with grails you would have few options (grails views, marshallers etc). But without it, you may have to consider rolling your own json renderer on the lines of a grails marshallers. That's what we did for our grails app

Comment: Yes, Grails will hide by default many of these fields. What I'm looking for here is a method to get only the explicit defined fields for the object and all its descendants.